# Can't bind checkboxes in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a GridView that displays a list and the user can select a checkbox for each item.

[image]

So for example I check the second row. I can see in the database that the check value next to this description has updated to 1:

[image]

But when I go back into the GridView, all the checkboxes are blank again.

Code for GridView:

```
<asp:GridView  style="width:75%"  
                        ID="gvCVRTDetails" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound"                             
                        DataKeyField="ID" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistID" HeaderText="ID" ></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Checklist Items"></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Checked?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            lookupCVRT work = (lookupCVRT)e.Row.DataItem;
            GridView gv = sender as GridView;

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("ID", "gvCVRTDetails_" + work.ID);
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "event.stopPropagation();");

            CheckBox chkChecked = e.Row.FindControl("chkChecked") as CheckBox;

            if(work.Checked)
            {
                chkChecked.Checked = true;
            } 

        }
    }
```

I tried setting `chkChecked.Checked = true;` if there is a value for the Checked field in the database but that didn't work. How do I get the checkboxes to show as ticked if the value in the database is equal to 1?

Binding the Grid:

```
 protected void gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<lookupCVRT> workDetails = lookupCVRT.GetChecklistItemsByChecklistID(Company.Current.CompanyID, ParentID.ToString(), gvCVRT.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
        gvCVRTDetails.DataSource = workDetails;
        gvCVRTDetails.DataBind();
        FireJavascriptCallback("setArgAndPostBack ();");

    }
```

Comment: That is a strange way to bind values to checkboxes inside gridview, but it generally looks ok on the first glance. Did you try to debug it?

Comment: @Andrei Yes I debugged it and it goes into the if statement but when I look at the Grid the checkboxes are still blank

Comment: @Andrei I also tried adding `Checked='<%# Bind("Checked") %>'` to the grid but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the checkbox to the property that you read from db, something like:

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Checked?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
              <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked"  Checked='<%# Bind("YourCheckPropertyFromModel") %>'runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
              </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I also tried `Checked='<%#bool.Parse(Eval("Checked").ToString())%>'` but that didn't work either

Comment: any other ideas for this? I still can't get it to work